# Trying to refactor ruby code so parameter list isn't so long

Tags: ruby

If I have a method with a parameter list like such:

```
def func(param1, param2, param3, para4, param5, param6)
```

what would be the best way to get rid of the long list? There are suggestion to create a separate object, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: Is this method part of a module or class? Can you provide the containing code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) `*` splat in Ruby:

```
def f(*p)
   p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8=*p
   p p
   p p8
end

f(*(1..8).to_a)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# 8
```

There are tradeoffs here. You loose the interpreter's help in counting the args actually passed to the method.

By doing:

```
p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8=*p
```

any arguments more than 8 to the method will be silently ignored and if less than 8, the shortfall will be silently assigned `nil`:

```
> f(1,2,3)
[1, 2, 3]
nil
```

If that is OK, the `*` is a useful shortcut.

You can also use an empty array as a default arg:

```
def f2(p=[])
    p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8=*p
    p p
    p p8
end
```

Then call without the *splat* since now the method is expecting one argument, not a variable number:

```
f2(1..8)
```

With the same comment regarding the array length apply: arguments lengths greater than 8 are silently ignored and less than 8 are silently assigned `nil`

You can add argument checking to variable length arguments if desired:

```
def f(*p)
   args_expected=8
   raise ArgumentError, "\"#{__method__}\": wrong number of arguments (given %d expected %d)" % [p.length, args_expected] if p.length !=args_expected
   p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8=*p
end

> f(1,2,3)
ArgumentError: "f": wrong number of arguments (given 3 expected 8)
```

But now you are adding words and complexity back.

There are good reasons to use named positional arguments if you are expecting a fixed number of arguments. The function is easy to change and you are allowing the interpreter help you.

Comment: This is best if the arguments themselves are somewhat arbitrary and shouldn't be used as a substitute for properly named arguments.

Comment: I agree with @tadman. This solution is good either, but as not as clearer as using properly named arguments. And you depend on the order of the arguments to set them correctly with `*p`.

Comment: @tadman: I agree with you. After a bit of coffee, I will add a caution.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion would be to use a single hash with the parameters as keys/options.

```
def func(hash_param = {})
  param1 = hash_param[:param1]
  param2 = hash_param[:param2]
  param3 = hash_param[:param3]
  param4 = hash_param[:param4]
  param5 = hash_param[:param5]
  param6 = hash_param[:param6]
  #rest_of_code
end

hash = {
  param1: 'foo',
  param2: 'bar',
  param3: 'baz',
  param4: 'qux',
  param5: 'alice',
  param6: 'bob'
}

func(hash)
```

If some specific keys inside the hash are not defined, they will simply return `nil`.

Comment: Even easier is the new hash notation for declaring: `def func(a: nil, b: nil, c: nil, ...)` where each can be given default values, or not if you don't want to.

Comment: Or `def func(**hash_param)` for wildcard keys